# Why does NodeJS need a linked list structure to contain all those registered native module?

Tags: node.js

[image]

I think a "std::map" structure would be better for module object searching.

Here is the link to the specific source code:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/07cb69720bec251a1c450b3770db2136ac009778/src/node.h#L503

Comment: So, is your question why they are using a linked list instead of `std::map`?  Or is your question why they have this list of modules at all?

Comment: Yes, my question is "why they are using a linked list instead of std::map?"

Comment: Questions like this are hard to get an answer to on stackoverflow because really only the people who participated in writing that specific section of code the way it was written know the answer for "why?".